# Advantages and Disadvantages of Forced Code Reformat

Tags: java, formatting, coding-standards

I'm currently working at a place that may be looking at forcing developers to use an automated code formatter on version control check-in.  I'm looking for developers opinions on the advantages and disadvantages of doing this ... how you think it would help or hinder developers. My specific case involves Java/JSPs, but I think the question could apply to any language.

Comment: JSP auto-reformat? That includes HTML/XML code and reformatting that can very easily break/change the resulting output.

Comment: Related: [Is imposing the same code format for all developers a good idea?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/189274/is-imposing-the-same-code-format-for-all-developers-a-good-idea)

Comment: You may find this blog post of mine relevant: [The Educational Aspect of Static Analysis](https://www.yegor256.com/2018/01/16/educational-aspect-of-static-analysis.html)

Answer (score 24):

I think it's *very* important to do this. Here's why:

- It makes your source control diffs show *just* actual code changes, and all but eliminates "diff noise" due to whitespace and other insignificant formatting choices
- It makes all code more similar, so that devs are more comfortable pairing and sharing the code bases

If you do it, I would recommend everyone check all code in, then one person does a reformat over the whole code base, then checks it all back in so there's one "giant" change set for formatting (that everyone can ignore), but after that, all diffs are real code diffs.

If you do it bit by bit, you'll be mixing real code changes with formatting changes and things will get unnecessarily messy in change land.

Comment: Biting the bullet on a global change is really the best way, I agree; get it done and no one has to worry about it ever again.

Comment: ... until you change your style convention.

Comment: @Nerdfest Then you apply your new convention on all your project in a single commit. That's no big deal.

Comment: Your "diff" tool kind of sucks if it can't handle whitespace changes properly.

Comment: There are always going to be exceptions where a slightly different format is likely cleaner than the prescribed style. Auto-converting can thus often hide the intent of certain code blocks, which is effectively just as good as adding a defect to the code.

Comment: Thanks for that comment ... I'm going to add it to me disadvantages list, unless you'd like to create your own entry. If you create one let me know and I'll edit mine.

Comment: @edA-qa mort-ora-y The disadvantage is almost always trivially solved by writing the code considering what the formarter will do with it. Often the reason the formatter cannot get it "right" is because it's unclear or overly complex anyway.

Comment: @mattnz, you said it yourself, "*almost always*". And I don't disagree that you might be able to reformat it right by hand, but in the meantime the auto-formatter has come and made a mess of it.

Comment: @edA-qa mort-ora-y My point being that for the very rare time that it makes a difference, the rest of the time it makes life so much easier. It's like people who wont were saftey belts because if you crash into a river you might drown - and they live in a desert

Comment: @mattnz: Having a check-in tool reformat code without having the programmer see and approve the changes first seems dangerous.  On the other hand, a tool which would give programmers a chance to examine changes and ensure that things still work as intended would be helpful.  Too bad more languages don't offer a practical way to test whether two source files will yield semantically-equivalent output code, since that would be a useful thing to know.

Answer (score 11):

I'm going to toss my own answer here as people only seem to be adding advantages. What I see as disadvantages are:

- Eliminates the ability to do 'better' than the auto-formatter ... it will undo your cleaner formatting. An example of this would be column-based parameter declarations, lists of discrete additions of objects, etc.
- Creates a resistance to changing style conventions as these will now create large misleading diff changes.
- Removes the ability to do any 'special-case' formatting where an alternate format would make code more readable.
- It ties you into using IDEs which support *exactly* the reformatting features you need. In another IDE is missing one of the options you need, it will cause at least some problems.
- It becomes problematic sharing a writable code repository with an external group unless they use exactly the same format conventions as your group (They usually will, but not always).
- There are always going to be exceptions where a slightly different format is likely cleaner than the prescribed style. Auto-converting can thus often hide the intent of certain code blocks, which is effectively just as good as adding a defect to the code.

Simply put, a non-automated set of conventions sets minimum style/readability requirements, where automated conventions set a minimum and a maximum.

I remember looking at VB (version 5 maybe) and finding one of the most annoying things about it was that it would forcibly reformat my code and remove things above and beyond its basic formatting.

Comment: One formating convention over another rarely gives any benefit if it comes at the expense of consistency. You get use to it. Follow Bohemian's advice and create a grace period to help determine the formating styles and then stick with them. Changing the format should not be taken lightly anyway.

Comment: @Jeff, I don't believe he's advocating inconsistent code formatting, but rather consistent code formatting that is difficult to automate.  For example, many coding styles specify aligning columns in an aesthetic manner when you have several lines of related data together.  This greatly enhances readability, but is very difficult to automate definitions of "aesthetic" or "related."  That's the reason some code formatters will allow manual formatting to override under certain circumstances.

Comment: Its far better to have consistent format 99.9% of the time and put up with the odd bit you personally don't like, than to put up with an undisciplined mismash.  I probably depends how disciplined the team is where the balance lies. 

If you stick to the established norms for a language, all decent editors/IDEs will be capable of formating that way. If you insist on moving from the norms, you will have trouble.

Comment: Thanks for presenting the other side. I do think that your points 1, 3, and 6 boil down to the same thing, and can be solved by occasional use of //@formatter:off.

Answer (score 4):

I find that forced code formatting is great.  It allows a developer to traverse the entire corpus of code without having their eyes bounce everywhere.  Also having this standard in place helps novice developers break bad habits.

Answer (score 3):

Primary disadvantage is losing custom formatting where it really matters.

Imagine a typical sanity check if() that will fail if any of the specific conditions is present but not fulfilled...

```
  if(
      (user.id == TEST_ID)
    ||(
         (user.id == UserID)
       &&( 
             ( user.type == HUMAN_USER && user.name.size() >= MIN_NAME )
           ||( user.type == EMULATION && input.source != SOURCE_INTERNAL ))
       && ( user.email == NULL || emailValidator.isValid(user.email))
       && ( (user.phone == NULL) == (user.type == EMULATION) )

       // several more lines like this.)
    ){ /* handle results */ }
```

This is readable thanks to reasonable indenting following the logical structure of the conditions.

Now your automated tool has no clue about logical separation of different conditions into related lines. It sees no reason why each clump 3-4 conditions in one line and split the next condition in half. Or it will split it, one comparison expression per line. It may even look prettier on screen but the logic will be lost.

Comment: This is mess, my positron brain just melted. So much inconsistency with whitespace around ( and ). That's exactly why we need machines to format the code.

And you could always put single line comment before/after (depends on your convention) to force condition grouping. It would also be helpful to explain reader the business rules behind this conditions - right in this single line comments.

Comment: @ŠtefanOravec: Run this through an autoformatter and apply these comments. See if it's more readable. Test user - always. Human users with valid usernames. Emulated users - only external sources. Email, if present, must be valid. Human users must have a phone number; emulated - must not. See how your single-line comments align with the autoformatted code.

Comment: This seems like a great example of why you should use automatters. An autoformatter might give an unreasonable result here because this is a massively complex, incomprehensible condition that needs to be broken up. It exhibits very idiosyncratic, personal styling choices in indentation and spacing that may look good to its author, but not to most. If you broke these conditions out to one or more functions, the formatter would have no problem with it. In other words, autoformatters help hold programmers accountable--if the code looks bad on auto-format, in most cases, it probably _is_ bad.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, it's a good thing.  Without one, code compares often show a mess of whitespace formatting, and may hide actual code changes.  In my experience, messing with someone's formatting isn't the sin it's made out to be, especially with the potential benefits of consistency across the team.

Answer (score 2):

I've added an answer with disadvantages, and I'll throw in what I consider a big advantage as well.

When you use an automated code reformat on commit, it does actually opens up the possibility of personal preference variations without the usual effect of having your preferences inflicted on others. You can have your IDE format code to a common standard on commit, but display it to you in your preferred format without affecting others.

This to me is almost the Holy Grail of convention based coding ... you get the advantages of a common code format, but still allow personal preferences to be supported without conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your needs but some contraints are quite helpful, e.g. every if() should be followed by curly braces, since it's quite easy to get such an if wrong if you're refactoring.

Consider that case:

```
if( x == 0 ) 
   return foo;
//do something else
return bar;
```

If you now want to add some logging to the if case you might accidentially write:

```
if( x == 0 ) 
  log.info("x was 0");
  return foo;
//do something else
return bar;
```

And suddently your method always returns `foo`.

Edit: that's not on automatic formatting but rather style checking. Sorry if that answer was off topic as well. :)

Comment: That's more a code style thing, not a formatting thing. There are build tools for that.

Comment: @Bohemian, you're right, I misread the question. The build tool of our choice is checkstyle btw. :)

Comment: Autoformatters would actually help catch this because they'll de-indent the `return` to match its true block, and probably add braces as well, making the error very obvious. That said, any good compiler or linter should detect the unreachable statement.

Comment: @ggorlen I'm not so sure I'd want to rely on the compiler or linter as not all cases would lead to unreachable statements. Also, while auto-formatters would help detect this by creating a code smell it would still depend on a human to actually read the code again and understand the original intent. To me having a constraint in place to force developers to explicitly state their intent, e.g. by adding curlies, is preferable to guessing or trying to spot unintended errors after the fact - even though this might add some inconvenience.

Comment: Autoformatters can add those braces. Sure, one should be on the lookout for unreachable statements, but the point is that autoformatting will make logical/flow errors more obvious on sight than not, so this does seem like a genuine advantage. Compilers and linters on full blast settings are also important (probably more so, but finding bugs is a team effort).

Comment: @ggorlen yes, autoformatters can add curlies but they might get it wrong and an important statement being pushed out of the block might be a not so obvious but critical error. Don't just think about return statements etc. but it could also be flags or other data being written conditionally at first but unconditionally after the code insertion. Autoformatting would hide that change from conditional to unconditional writes and it now requires more effort to even spot that bug. A situation like this with the bug not having been spotted caused a major security issue with iOS a couple of years ago.

Comment: Any decent autoformatter won't change the meaning of the code. That's a critical, basic invariant. They need to be trustworthy enough to be able to be [applied to an entire codebase](https://github.com/django/django/pull/15387/) without causing regressions. I don't follow what you mean about conditionals. Can you provide an example of this? If it did occur, that's a bug with a specific autoformatter, not necessarily a critique of autoformatters in general, except to argue that maybe they have hidden bugs that change the meaning of code often enough that it's a problem.

Comment: @ggorlen just to prevent any potential misunderstanding: I'm pro autoformatters and never wanted to imply anything else. What I want to bring across is that autoformatters alone cannot catch every type of error and that's why I'm also in favor of additional constraints on the code. ...

Comment: Let me try a simplified example (I can't format well in comments so just imagine this is using indentation and linebreaks): consider the following code which is not using curlies: `if(isAuthorized(user)) doSensitiveAction();` - now some developer wants to add some logging before calling `doSensitiveAction()`: `if(isAuthorized(user)) log.info("user is authorized"); doSensitiveAction();` - now all of a sudden `doSensitiveAction()` falls out of the block and is called in any case - would the autoformatter be able to catch the scope of the method changing?

Comment: I never claiimed autoformatters catch every error, only that they make certain classes of errors like the one in this post more obvious. In the example you shared, it seems if you don't autoformat, the code will visually look like the `doSensitiveAction()` call is part of the block when it's been kicked out by the logger. The autoformatter will override the "looks like part of the block" and potentially add braces, making the problem more obvious. They steer you away from shooting yourself with misleading formatting practices like skipping braces.

Comment: @ggorlen yes that's true. What I tried to bring across though is that certain constraints that hit before the autoformatters may be even more useful. Instead of having an autoformatter add braces I'd rather force the devs to always add them by themselves so they have to explicitly state what goes into a block. Code that's autoformatted and would highlight errors isn't useful if nobody looks at it until it's too late.

Answer (score 0):

It greatly helps to uniform the code in the company, and thanks to that you generally produce a more easily understandable and way more easily maintainable structure for your product.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the advantages are the same as any code formatter, like standardization of the code, semantic between developers, etc. The only possible disadvantages I see is the lack of a human eye *after* the formatting, to add some exceptions, etc. 
So I guess is better consider a IDE formatter instead of a check-in time formatter.